# malformed lambda proxy response, can't find the error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get data from my api using lambda and API Gateway, when sending the get requests I get this error:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
```

the code returns:

```
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy response must be a dictionary which [must only contain the following keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format):

- `headers`
- `body`
- `isBase64Encoded`
- `multiValueHeaders`
- `statusCode`

In your example you have one additional key `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and that's why API Gateway claims that it is a malformed response. The documentation linked above even explicitly states that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be part of `headers`:

> To enable CORS for the Lambda proxy integration, you must add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:domain-name` to the output `headers.domain-name` can be `*` for any domain name.

If you change the response to the following it should work fine:

```python
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'isBase64Encoded': False,
    'body': json.dumps(data)
}
```